# Capybara Webkit not detecting CSS updates when DOM changes

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have a floating menu that pops up when a user clicks on a menu button (button is hidden behind the floating menu in the image below).

[image]

The functionality works fine in a live browser (tried it on Firefox, Safari, and Chrome).

However it doesn't seem to work when testing with Capybara-Webkit - the menu never becomes visible on click

Here's the basic implementation:

### HTML

The menu is a `<ul>` that sits inside a `<div>`

```
<div class="location-card">
  ...

  <div class="location-card__menu-btn">
    <%= inline_svg("icons/menu-btn-icon.svg", height: "20px", width: "20px") %>

    <ul class="location-card__menu">
      <li>Delete</li>
      <li>Open</li>
      <li>Share</li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

### JS

Simple javascript/jquery sets a toggle class (`location-card--menu-open`) on the top-level `<div>` whenever the button is clicked.

```
$(".location-card").on("click", ".location-card__menu-btn", function(e) {
  // Find the card element top-level div
  var card = $(e.currentTarget).parents(".location-card");

  // Set the toggle class 
  $(card).addClass("location-card--menu-open");
});
```

### CSS

Finally, the CSS for the menu defaults to `display: none`, but is changed to `display: flex` when the toggle class is present on the parent.

```
.location-card__menu {
  display: none;
  ...
}

.location-card--menu-open .location-card__menu {
  display: flex;
  ...
}
```

### RSpec / Capybara

When testing I do the following:

```
// Click the menu button
find(".location-card__menu-btn").click

// Verify that the menu opened and is visible
expect(page).to have_selector(".location-card__menu", visible: true)
```

to which Capybara throws the errror:

```
expected to find visible css ".location-card__menu" within #<Capybara::Node::Element ... > but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

As the error says, the element is found but is not visible even though the toggle class is added correctly. The CSS rule that adds the `display: flex` is not being applied even though the toggle class exists on the parent.

I can verify this is the issue by removing the `display: none` to have the menu displayed by default and then everything works great and the test passes.

Any idea why Capybara or the underlying browser might be failing to re-apply the CSS logic once the DOM changes?

I'm using:

- rspec-rails 3.4.0
- capybara 2.18.0
- capybara-webkit 1.15.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`capybara-webkit` is basically equivalent to a 7 year old version of Safari (due to QtWebkit, which it is built on, not having been updated in a long time).  As such it doesn't support a lot of modern JS/CSS, which happens to include flex box. Because of this `display: flex` will be considered invalid and ignored.

You're going to have a much easier time testing your app if you swap from using `capybara-webkit` to selenium with headless chrome or firefox for your headless testing.